# Chart in report child is not resizable in report parent

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, subreport

I've got one report(called it report_child, i.e) inside a simple report in SSRS 2012 (chart-dataset) and it's fine.
Now, I've created one general report (called it report_parent i.e), and I want to embed the initial report_child chart in report_parent.

I embed it using subreport (report_parent contains a subreport called report_child) and all it's fine, but the problem is the initial chart size in the child_report is the same in the parent_report and it's not posible change it.

Is it mandatory an element of child_report cannot be resizable in the report parent?

SqlServer2012 SSRS12

Comment: I think the answer to your problem is no?  I think you need to resize the elements in the subreport, not the actual subreport item to adjust the size.  I can't really be sure without any pictures showing your issue, but try to resize the elements in the subreport and see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: If I try to resize the char in the subreport, the size of the figure in the report parent change too. The problem is that I want differente sizes in the subreport and in the report, because both reports are being used by the user.

Comment: Then you might just want to create a duplicate report of the subreport because the size in the parent will always match the size in the child report.  Not really an elegant solution to this problem.